# CONVERT() working only when other columns in SELECT query

Tags: sql, sql-server

Bear with me on this one, I'm not great at explaining!

I'm trying to do a simple `UPDATE`, converting data from dd/MM/yyyy to yyyy-MM-dd. However I get the error:

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string

Normally, a pretty easy error to debug...

However, whilst debugging I decided to retrieve all of the columns from the table as well as the converted column on the end... Which works fine?! Column converted, all rows returned, no problems:

```
SELECT 
    x.*, 
    CONVERT(date, x.[date], 103) test 
FROM 
    table_name x 
WHERE 
    import_date = (SELECT MAX(import_date) FROM table_name) 
ORDER BY 
    part_num DESC
```

But this is where I'm even more confused. If I remove the `x.*` reference and only return the converted column, it returns the error message above.

I am almost certain I am being very, very silly and it's incredibly simple where I've gone wrong, but can someone please help?!

EDIT:
As suggested with the first reply, I used `TRY_CONVERT()` as follows. All returned 'Cast succeeded':

```
SELECT CASE WHEN TRY_CONVERT(date, date,103) IS NULL   
THEN 'Cast failed'  
ELSE 'Cast succeeded'  END FROM table_name WHERE import_date = (SELECT MAX(import_date) FROM table_name)
```

Comment: Run the validation test without your `WHERE` filter.

Comment: Well yes, that will fail because the other values in that column have already been converted to the correct format. My update statement has the same WHERE filter on, so I'm failing to see where the point of removing it would be?

Comment: Apologies if that came across as short - it wasn't intended that way! I appreciate all suggestions.

Comment: I know it is a bit late for this but if you stored the data as datetime there would be no reason for you to even be asking a question. Choosing the correct datatype is critical.

Comment: Very useful answer, I've just learned something new! The data is being imported from an excel spreadsheet via a SSIS package with the date in a format of dd/MM/yyyy. I didn't realise that it would auto-convert dd/MM/yyyy to datetime format! I thought I'd have to do that after the fact, hence the question. I've recreated the table and reimported. Thanks for your suggestion!

Comment: @jaygale23 make sure to use date/datetime columns when storing dates, and if you have to write them as litertals, write them in ISO format (yyyy-MM-dd) so it doesn't bring confusion of days and months.

Comment: I would highly recommend fixing the invalid dates first, even if is it going to be manually fixed. Then, convert them to whatever format you want.

Answer (score 2):

Presumably, you have a bad date value.  This may occur in a row that is filtered out, which is why you get the error sometimes or not -- depending on how the filtering is implemented.

Just find the bad values using:

```
SELECT date
FROM test
WHERE TRY_CONVERT(date, x.[date], 103) IS NULL AND x.[date] IS NOT NULL;
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! However, see my edit above. TRY_CONVERT() worked for all rows...

Comment: @jaygale23 You missed Gordon's point.  Run the suggested query and you'll see.  The EDIT you've made has filter on what is (presumably) a valid date.

Comment: Okay, I have ran the above query and it returns every value, converted as it should be. Am I missing something?

Comment: If you ran @Gordon's query, and it returned rows, these are the rows that **can not** be converted to `DATE`. Thus, **all** your data would be bad @jaygale23

Comment: Yes, but that returns the values in the table that have already been converted previously, hence the WHERE clause in my question. I know it will fail to convert all of the data in the column.

Comment: @jaygale23 . . . Use `try_convert()` in your query if you know that some of the values are bad.